# Forward declare other nested struct in C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes, forward-declaration

I'm trying to implement the visitor pattern inside of another class. MWE:

```
struct super
{
    struct base
    {
        virtual void accept(struct visitor& v);
        virtual ~base() {}
    };

    struct visitor
    {
        virtual void visit(base& b);
        virtual ~visitor() {}
    };

    struct special : public base
    {
        void accept(visitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
    };
};

int main() {}
```

This complains that `special::accept` is actually not overriding anything. I guess this is because of `struct visitor` being different to `visitor`.

Swapping the position of base and visitor (and moving the forward declaration to `visitor::visit`) vanishes this error (but then says that the argument in `v.visit(*this)` would not match).

Is it possible to implement the visitor pattern inside another class? Why does my forward declaration not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
virtual void accept(struct visitor& v);
```

you forward declare `visitor` [in the
smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.pdecl#7.2.sentence-1). That means `visitor is scoped to the global namespace in this case.`specials`'s

```
void accept(visitor& v)
```

on the other hand is grabbing `super::visitor`.  Since those are different types the compiler is correct.

What you need to do is move the forward declaration of `visitor` into `super`'s scope like

```
struct super
{
    struct visitor;
    struct base
    {
        virtual void accept(visitor& v);
        virtual ~base() {}
    };

    struct visitor
    {
        virtual void visit(base& b);
        virtual ~visitor() {}
    };

    struct special : public base
    {
        void accept(visitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
    };
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: I understand your explanation. But, why does `struct visitor; struct base { virtual void accept(struct visitor& v)` (keeping the `struct` in `accept` and just adding `struct visitor;`) not lead to a compile error? Shouldn't that then still be the same problem as the OP had before.

Comment: @t.niese Unfortunately no.  C++ inherits a lot of things from C to be backwards compatible and one of those things was using `struct` when you declare you are using an object that is a `struct`.  So `struct visitor; struct base { virtual void accept(struct visitor& v)` forward declares a `struct` named `visitor` and the the function just says it is using that struct, not forward declaring it.  In C++ when you use `struct` it is ignored, unless that `struct` doesn't exist, then it forward declares it.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I extend your logic to the same MWE, but without the surrounding `super` class, you say I'm forward declaring `base::visitor`, which is not `visitor` and the issue would be the same. Why is your argumentation not applicable if there is no `super`?

Comment: Sorry for bothering. Is it really `super::base::visitor` or a complete distinct type. I just tested around with `struct base { void foo(struct test& v) {} struct test {}; void bar(test& v) {  foo(v); } };` which does not compile either or is that about the same C backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Johannes Can you show me an example where this isn't wroking the way I say it should?  I'm not understanding your comment.

Comment: @t.niese Sorry, I was incorrect with where the name was scoped to.  It is actually scoped to the global namespace, not the class, per the link in the post.

Comment: @Johannes I've updated my answer.  The forward declaration of `visitor` in your example actually declares it in the global space, not the class space as I has stated.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for pointing this out. I had to read that three times. This rule looks counter-intuitive, I'd really have expected that `visitor` is declared in the smallest namespace or block **or class** scope that contains the declaration. You don't have randomly any idea why the **class** is not relevant?

Comment: @Johannes I'm only guessing but it is the behavior that most closely matches what would happen in C, and C++ tried in a lot of places to act like C to get C++ programmers to want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring

```
struct super
{
    struct base
    {
        virtual void accept(struct visitor& v);
        virtual ~base() {}
    };
};
```

Does not make `visitor` a member of `base` nor a member of `super`. It actually forward declares global `::visitor`. This is why in C++, it is considered very bad style to forward declare a type inside some other declaration. Base class function accept has the signature `void accept(::visitor&)` but derived class has signature `void accept(super::visitor&)`. The MWE you wrote would be equivalent to the following code:

```
struct super
{
    struct base
    {
        // Declares ::visitor
        // Same signature as: virtual void accept(::visitor&);
        virtual void accept(struct visitor& v);
        virtual ~base() {}
    };

    // Declares super::base::visitor
    struct visitor
    {
        virtual void visit(base& b);
        virtual ~visitor() {}
    };

    struct special : public base
    {
        // Must have signature void accept(::visitor&) to override
        void accept(::visitor& v) override;
    };
};

struct visitor
{
    virtual void visit(super::base& b);
    virtual ~visitor() {}
};

inline void super::special::accept(::visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }

int main() {}
```

Comment: Indeed you probably never need (or want) to use `struct` in a function declaration in C++. It's too obscure and an indication of a lack of forward declaration.